# How to get the Windows "Digit Grouping" setting

Tags: winapi, localization, vb6

In the Windows Regional control panel is a "Digit Grouping" setting, which indicates whether the Indian numbering system is used, where the thousands separator character groups the first three digits to the left of the decimal together, and thereafter every two digits, vs. the more common grouping where every three digits to the left the decimal are grouped together.

How can I get that setting in VB6?

Or, alternatively, what is the best way to determine when to use that Indian numbering system?

Comment: `GetLocaleInfoEx()` with `LOCALE_SGROUPING` is the function - no idea about vb6 however.

Comment: When you use the `FormatNumber()` function you can pass `vbUseDefault`  for the `GroupDigits` argument (or omit it).  Then it should format according to the current locale settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Private Const LOCALE_SGROUPING = &H10
Private Const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = &H400
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) as Long

Private Function Grouping() As String
  Dim retVal As Long, sBuf As String
  sBuf = String(255, vbNullChar)
  retVal = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SGROUPING, sBuf, Len(sBuf))
  Grouping = Left$(sBuf, retVal - 1)
End Function
```

Example: will output: `3;0` for 123.456,789 and `3;2;0` for 12.34.56,789

Answer (score 0):

As Bob77 said in a comment, why not just let [`FormatNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443995(v=vs.60).aspx) do it for you? It will apply the digit grouping from the regional settings. Like this

```
MsgBox(FormatNumber(123456, , , , vbUseDefault))
```

*"air code" - I have not tried this myself*

Comment: Thanks, but this is for an arbitrary precision program which calculates numbers with more than the 15 significant digits of precision that most programs can handle, and returns them as text formatted to look like a number. Example result: "1,234,567,891.2345678912". If you try to do that with a number in most programs, it will be truncated to 1,234,567,891.23456 (15 significant digits of precision). So, FormatNumber doesn't work because anything that VB6 sees as a numeric data type doesn't work. The program does math with text strings.